Game Theory Extensive Game
1st question: What is the SPNE?
My answer: A(BW), B(W): (2,1)
2st question: Show the game at its strategic form
My answer:




B
W




BB
2,1
1,2


BW
1,1
2,1


WW
3,0
0,3


WB
3,0
0,3



3rd question: Find all the NE.
My answer: There is only one, 2,1.
4th question: Which of them are unreliable and why?
Myanswer: What?
5th question: How would you change they payoffs so that a SPNE doesn't exist?
My answer: No clue
3rd question: How many NE there are?
4th question: Which of them are unreliable and why?
5th question: How would you change the payoffs so that the game doesn't have an SPNE?


A has three information sets with two actions each, so it has 8 pure strategies, not 4. Something like "1, 2" cannot be a NE since NE are strategy profiles.
